# Triggering onActivityResult from another activity

Tags: android, android-intent

What I'm looking to do here is have the `onActivityResult` method fired, from an activity that is calling `startActivity`. The issue is that an application will handle certain file types, however, the MIME type isn't properly setup, so when I try to open the file type, ".xyz", I'm not prompted to associate it with the application. I did, however, find the activity that is designed to handle this in their package.

So here's what I'm trying to do.

```
MyClass.java
setFakeResult(RESULT_OK)
intent i = new intent
i.putExtras("filepath", "/sdcard/file.xzy");
startActivityForResult(com.Package.whatever.TheirClass, i);

TheirClass.java
onActivityResult {
    if (result == RESULT_OK)
        String fileLocation =  intent.getExtra("filepath")
        loadFile("filepath")
```

^ That part is really bad pseudo-code, but i think it illustrates the point i'm trying to make. I'm trying to forcefully call 'onActivityResult' and included data i've bundled into the intent. Is there a way to do this?

[Edit]

To Sepecify. There is a compiled application that opens the file type ".xyz". They did not properly setup the MimeType, so if I try to open `*.xyz` from ES File Explorer, I cannot choose their application. I found that their activity, `com.package.whatever.TheirClass` contains an onActivityResult, that looks for 'filename' in bundled extras, in `onActivityResult`. I'm trying to start THEIR activity in such a way that onActivityResult is immediately called, with bundled data that I provided.

Comment: `onActivityResult ` should be in your `MyClass` itself and you should set the result in `TheirClass`

Comment: Except they have a compiled application that I cannot modify.

Comment: You can't do this. `onActivityResult()` will only be called on their activity if their activity starts another activity using `startActivityForResult()`.